# Pyinstaller не видит dll при конвертировании в ехе

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Пытаюсь конвертировать python в exe с помощью pyinstaller, раньше проблем с ним не было, но щас возникла проблема при использовании pyqt5.

Запускаю конвертирование так :

```
python pyinstaller.py test2.py --onefile
```

где `test2.py`- конвертирование формулы latex в изображение

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.set_axis_off()
t = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, "sin(x)",
horizontalalignment='center',
verticalalignment='center',
fontsize=20, color='black')
ax.figure.canvas.draw()
bbox = t.get_window_extent()
fig.set_size_inches(bbox.width / 80, bbox.height / 80) # dpi=80
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=120)
```

При запуске конвертирования не может найти дллки для pyqt5 , хотя они есть, ну и соответственно при запуске готового ехе дает ошибку

```
Failed to execute script pyi_rth_qt5plugins
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --paths C:\Users\...\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin test2.py
```

Comment: спасибо большое